# How to stop webpage scrolling to top when clicking a like button. node js, mongoose, javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

Every time the like button is clicked, the webpage scrolls to the top. Any ideas how to stop this from happening. The code is ,

```
<a href="/likeComment/{{../post._id}}/{{_id}}"> 
          <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up"></i>
          {{likes.length}} Like
        </a>
```

The like is registered and the number of likes is incremented. However, it jumps to the top of the webpage every time it is clicked. I want the webpage to stay where it is when the like is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It's the default behavior of an anchor `<a>` element with an `href`. When you click on it can cause the page to jump to the top.

Changing it to: `<button>` or `<div>` should resolve the issue.

Comment: This stops the page scrolling but it also stops the likes from registering and therefore the number of likes does not increment when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this by adding onclick to the element

```
<a href="/likeComment/{{../post._id}}/{{_id}}" id="test" onclick="updateLikes(event, '{{../post._id}}', '{{_id}}')"> 
      <i class="fa-solid fa-thumbs-up"></i>
      {{likes.length}} Like
    </a>
```

then using AJAX to update the like count.

```
  // Prevent the default link behavior
  event.preventDefault();


  const url = `/likeComment/${postId}/${commentId}`;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);


  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // The like count was successfully updated on the server
      // Now, reload the page to reflect the new like count
      location.reload();
    }
  };


  xhr.send();
}`
```

Comment: You have made good progress here, but I would suggest changing the anchor tag (`<a>`) to a button tag (`<button>`). As it no longer navigates to a new URL, it is more semantically correct for the element to be a button.